# Optimization with continuous and discrete variables

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to maximize the following problem:

$$
\sum_{t=1}^T{z_t g_t + (1-z_t) h_t(x_t) }
$$
with respect to $z_t$ which is a vector of 0 and 1 only and $x_t$ which is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^T$. $h_t$ is a known vector of concave function and $g_t$ is a known vector. The initial state ($t=0$) is perfectly known.

In words, I would like to find the path for $x_t$ but allowing for discrete choice, i.e. if I choose $z_t = 1$, then I do not update the value of $x_t$ and $x_t = x_{t-1}$ but if I choose $z_t=0$ I maximize with respect to $x_t$.

What is the best method to do this? I have found solutions for a full discrete choice model but not for a model that mixes a continuous and discrete variable.

Thanks

T.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new variable $y_t$ to represent the summand so that the objective is to maximize $\sum_t y_t$.  We want to enforce
$$y_t=\begin{cases}g_t &\text{if $z_t=1$}\\h_t(x_t) &\text{if $z_t=0$}\end{cases}$$
You can do this via the following big-M constraints:
\begin{equation}
(\ell_t-g_t)(1-z_t) \le y_t - g_t \le (u_t-g_t)(1-z_t)\\
(g_t - u_t) z_t \le y_t - h_t(x_t) \le (g_t - \ell_t)z_t,\\
\end{equation}
where $\ell_t$ and $u_t$ are (constant) lower and upper bounds on $h_t(x_t)$:
$$\ell_t \le h_t(x_t) \le u_t.$$
Now the objective and some constraints are linear.  If all $h_t$ are linear functions, then you can solve the whole problem with a MILP solver.  Otherwise, use a MINLP solver.

Comment: Thanks, how come the objective is now linear?

Comment: It is just a sum of the variables $y_t$.